# Get value of hash with multiple levels

Tags: ruby

I have a doubt, is there any way to get the value of `v` without putting, for example, `[:a][:b][:v]`?

```
{a: {b: {v: 'x'}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If already have the keys in hand, say

```
keys = [:a, :b, :v]
```

then, you can use [**`dig()`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) to get the value as:

```
hash = {a: {b: {v: 'x'}}}
hash.dig(*keys) #=> "x"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the keys but you know that each nested hash has just one key:

```
def dig_values(h)
  if h.is_a? Hash
    dig_values(h[h.keys.first])
  else
    return h
  end
end

dig_values(h) #=> "x"
```

It's a **recursive method** (as you can see in the body it calls itself) an uses these Ruby methods: [Hash#keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys), [Object#is_a?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) and [Enumerable#first](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first).

Comment: You might want to mention that this is recursive.